# How to make an empty link?

Tags: html

I have some clickable buttons that I made show/hide some div tags, and they work, but how do I make the cursor change so they look clickable? I was thinking either an html link that goes nowhere for cosmetic purposes or some sort of cursor change tag. Can I just type

```
<a href=".."></a>
```

Comment: I know this is an old question, but can I just say that `<a href="..">` is NOT an empty link. `..` is a well-defined URL that goes to a precisely specified location.

Answer (score 3):

You can use CSS.

```
cursor: pointer;
```